# Create star/snowflake schema from existing database (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, database-schema, snowflake-schema

I happen to find myself in a situation where i am using Oracle SQL Developer Version 1.5.5 and there's this huge database for which the documentation is very poor. I'd like to create a star or a snowflake schema for better understanding of the data. Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a data model **diagram**?  Star and snowflake are types of database design, you can't create one "of" an existing schema.

Answer (score 3):

You can reverse engineer the physical data model using [SQL Developer Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html). This is actually a separate tool from SQL Developer but shares some branding. It is also free.

The quality of the resultant diagram will depend heavily on how well the physical data structures have been implemented. You will only get relationships if the database has defined foreign key constraints (disabled is good enough). Likewise UIDs require defined primary key constraints. If your database lacks constraints you'll have to rely on column naming conventions, data analysis and your business knowledge.

Star or Snowflake schemas are for data warehouses. Is that the sort of database you're dealing with?

Comment: Thanks for your help i'll have to ask our admins to install it on my computer first before i try it out. 

Yes, it is a data warehouse with transactions. The database also has defined key contraints (thankfully :)).